# Processing and API's

Tags: twitter, processing

Here's the top chunk of the code:

```
import java.util.* ;

//Build an ArrayList to hold all of the words that we get from the imported tweets
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();

void setup() {
  //Set the size of the stage, and the background to black.
  size(800,800);
  background(0);
  smooth();
  frameRate(5);

  //Credentials
  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
```

I'm trying to do something similar to Jer Thorp's tutorial: http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/quick-tutorial-twitter-processing
I keep getting an error though: Cannot find a class or type named "ConfigurationBuilder"
I've tried to import stuff and keep getting errors when I try to drag and drop files- any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just drag the library `.jar` file onto the Processing editor. Make sure you get the correct `.jar` file, which you can check by either examining it as an archive file, or using the `jar tf` command.

You could also import the library using the Sketch -> Import Library menu. If the library isn't already installed, then you'll have to manually install it using the steps outlined here: http://wiki.processing.org/w/How_to_Install_a_Contributed_Library

Comment: Thanks I think that was my problem.